# Removing non integers from ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm mapping over a hash to create an array of numbers. There are a few elements that are not integers that I want to throw out entirely. Does anyone know how to do it? Or would I have to map over that array again and pull it out there?

Comment: Define "integer"? Are they strings? Are they actual `Integer` numerical values? It would really help if you could edit your question and add some sample data to add some specific context here.

Comment: It's actually a bunch of floats rounded to 3, like 1.543, 0.753, 0.385, then an SoS or some string.

Comment: @BethKnight What does SoS mean in this context?

Comment: "SoS", it's nothing and I need to get rid of it

Comment: @BethKnight So if you want to get only integers you can do `a.values.select{|i| Integer === i}` if you want to get numbers you can do `a.values.select{|i| Numeric === i}`

Comment: When you say non-integers, do you mean "not whole values" or do you mean "not of type Float"? A short snippet of sample data here with expected results is extremely important. Your descriptions are just a little too vague.

Comment: That worked work @EliSadoff. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example with desired output :)

Comment: Not type float @tadman

Comment: @Eli, "SoS", short for "Save our Souls", is the universal symbol of extreme danger or distress.Rubiests might send out an SOS, for example, if an important app that must absolutely, positively be deployed this Friday is not working.

Answer (score 6):

If you've already done any conversion on your input then it should be a simple case of selecting out the things you want:

```
hash.values.grep(Float)
```

That looks for anything that's a Float, or derived from Float if your code is so exotic as to have that going on.

It's worth noting that the `grep` tool is quite versatile. Most people presume it only works on strings or regular expressions, but it's actually a lot more capable than that.

Comment: A reminder of the power of `grep` is always appreciated. If the array might contain floats and integers, and you want both, `[2, 3.1, :cat].grep(Numeric) #=> [2, 3.1]`, as `Numeric === 2 #=> true` and `Numeric === 3.1 #=> true`.